# I need suggestions on C2C (Customer2Customer) PHP CMS

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, magento

I need to build a website for customers advertising such as craiglist.

I want to build it in PHP, and I 'm willing to use an open source CMS.

I'm a very big fan of Drupal, but I don't now if stands well for this kind of sites.

Could anyone suggest me a suitable CMS for my domain?

Best,
Demian

Comment: Voting to close as NPR, superuser.com might be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal is very capable to do that, so if you are already familiar with Drupal, I would stick to it.
Jeff Robbins from [Lullabot](http://www.lullabot.com) created a craigslist clone for demonstration purposes on the 'do it with drupal' seminar. You can find it at http://www.thieveslist.com/.